# Missing Firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm new to Ubuntu but familiar with Red Hat derivatives.

After installing, then updating a fresh installation of Ubuntu, Firefox disappeared. I search for it but could not find it, even though it was listed under default applications. I tried launching it via the command prompt without any success.

I googled this at best I could and learned about something named Snap. I decided to use snap to reinstall Firefox without it without any success. I went ahead and used snap to uninstall the invisible Firefox (just in case). I then used apt to reinstall it. A few days after it disappeared again.

I assumed this was due to automatic updates so I disabled that. I then went ahead and use apt to reinstall it. Hopefully it holds this time.

Can anyone explain why this happened or is happening?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Check if theres non snap version. Try "sudo apt install firefox"

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.

As I explained above, I did install the non-snap version only to have it disappear (probably after an update). Since I have disabled updates it's still there.